# MVC + code first EF + Execute stored procedure and binding it to entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have a `user` entity as follows:

```
 public int UserID { get; set; }
 public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
 public string UserName { get; set; }   and so on..
```

When I read the values using context to user entity everything works fine. But I have another table called `tbl_transactions_User`. Where I am using a trigger on `tbl_user` and inserting all the modified columns and their values. So let's say if I change my `DOB` value I am storing the prior data and updated data into the transaction table.

But the transaction table looks like:

```
[USER_KEY] [int] NULL,
[FIELD_NAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
[PRIOR_DATA] [varchar](255) NULL,
[UPDATED_DATA] [varchar](255) NULL
```

So when `DOB` column was modified in `tbl_insured` it will stored in `tbl_transactions_User` table. But as a `varchar` instead of actual `datetime`. So my `user` entity is expecting the `DOB` as `datetime`. But my stored procedure is returning values as `varchar` (I am using PIVOT and joins to get the modified column and its value from `tbl_transactions_user` and `tbl_user` tables)

So on my MVC front end it is returning error:

> The 'DOB' property on 'UserEntity' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'DateTime'.

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to convert your varchar type to datetime when you select it out in your stored procedure. How you do that depends on the format of the date when you are storing it as a string.

There are plenty of examples of conversion out there - here's one link: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: But i really don't know the data type of a field when i execute the store procedure. Because it just select the field name and its value from tbl_Transactions_user table in SP. It may be int datetime and decimal.

Comment: So are you using a generic stored procedure to get all data? It seems like you need an sp specifically for grabbing user data from the history table so that you know what data type you need to convert to.

Or you need more metadata. Track which column and/or type it is in the transaction table and use some CASE statements in the SQL to convert based on the metadata.